# Mulesoft_ Unable send email to multiple email address

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4

I can send an email for a single email address whereas if I configure more than one email address in the YAML file,I see some errors while sending an email for more than one email address.

Here is the configurations.

in the YAML:

```
db:
  to: "chandaka.chittibabu@astrazeneca.com,saikrishna.voleti@astrazeneca.com"
```

To address config:
selected Edit inline and added the below code under value
`{db.email} splitBy ","`

error:

```
Error while sending email: Error while creating {db.email} splitBy "," InternetAddress.
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to use an expression for the field. Inside the expression there is a configuration property (`db.email`). The error seems to be that the expression needs to be enclosed with `#[...]`. Also for using configuration properties in expressions you should use the p() function.

**Example**

YAML:

```
db:
  to: "chandaka.chittibabu@astrazeneca.com,saikrishna.voleti@astrazeneca.com"
```

In the flow:

```
<email:send toAddresses='#[ p("db.to") splitBy "," ]' ...
```

Comment: I still see that seeing the below errors while I use the above functions.       
Error while sending email: Exception reading response
{db.to}splitBy( ",")



#[ p("db.email") splitBy "," ]



Message               : "You called the function 'splitBy' with these arguments: 
  1: Null (null)
  2: String (",")

But it expects one of these combinations:
  (String, String)
  (String, Regex)

1| p("db.email") splitBy(",")

Comment: I used your expression as the base for my answer, but you are using `db.email` when the YAML defines `db.to`. So the `db.email` configuration property is not defined and returns null. I'll update my answer so it matches the YAML key.

Comment: Actually your error says you left the old expression. I updated my answer with the connector operation so you see the way to use it.